# What is the value of $\frac{\sin x}x$ at $x=0$?

Tags: limits, functions, trigonometry, fractions

On plotting graph for $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ using Wolfram|Alpha and Google, got that :
[image: plot of sin(x)/x]

also, I can get the value of $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$ using squeeze theorem and as illustrated on sources such as [MIT](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01sc-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/1.-differentiation/part-a-definition-and-basic-rules/session-8-limits-of-sine-and-cosine/MIT18_01SCF10_Ses8a.pdf).

But I'm not able to understand how the function is defined at $x=0$ and its value came out to be $1$ at that point. As promised in the plot for the function.

Using limits I got the idea about the behavior of the function in the neighborhood of that point but not its value exactly at $x=0$.

Comment: The function $f(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ is not defined in $0$ and so it is not cont. in $0$. However the function can be extended to continuous one which is cont. in zero: $g(x)=\sin(x)/x$ if $x\neq 0$ and $g(x)=1$ if $x=0$ ..

Comment: The function $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$ isn't defined at $x=0$, but it can be continuously extended to give the value $f(0)=1$.

Comment: we consider the behaviour of a function around a point $x=c$ and its possible value at that point differently. there is lots of explanations about this certain case on the web.

Comment: Note that a limit does not mean the function exists at the given point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A function  $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$ cannot be  defined for $x=0$ since division by $0$ is not defined in any numerical field. So this function is not continuous in $x=0$  but, since  ( as noted in OP) 
$$
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1
$$
the discontinuity is [removable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities#Removable_discontinuity) and the function defined as :
$$
f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R} \quad f(x)= \begin {cases}\frac{\sin x}{x} &\text{for }x \ne 0 \\ 1 &\text{for }x=0\end {cases}
$$

is continuous in $(-\infty, +\infty)$.

Comment: What makes this answer "better" than the others?  It is interesting to note that there is not concrete explanation on how any of this came to be.

Comment: I would not say that $f$ is not continuous at $x=0$. Continuity is only defined for points of the domain.

Answer (score 2):

The function is not defined at $x=0$.
But it can be continuously extended (since the limit from the left is equal to the limit from the right).

So the graph is not technically correct, it just shows the extended function.

Answer (score 2):

From the Maclaurin series expansion of $f(x)=\sin x$,we have that
$$\sin x=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\ldots$$

or, considering $x\not = 0,$ $$\frac{\sin x}{x}=1-\frac{x^2}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{5!}-\ldots$$
And hence by using the notion of uniform convergence of a power series, it can be said that
$$\lim_\limits{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$$

Thus at $x=0$, the function $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$ has R.H.L.=L.H.L.=$1 \not = f(0)$

So at $x=0$, $f(x)$ has removable discontinuity.

Hence to make the function continuous at $x=0$, $f(0)$ is defined to be $1$.

So the actual function should be like 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{\sin x}{x} &  x\not = 0 \\ \, \, \,  1 &  x=0\end{cases}$$

For the given function, it can be remarked that it is discontinuous at $x=0$.

Comment: And an explanation for the downvote?

Comment: You should include the part where you could divide your expansion by $x$, as it is easy to do.  I didn't down vote btw.

Comment: @SimpleArt I didn't get you.. which part are you talking of..?

Comment: You could divide the expansion by $x$ and substitute $x=0$ in.  ;)

Comment: @SimpleArt But then you have $0$ in the denominator! Division by $0$ is undefined... I don't like it also ;-)

Comment: I didn't downvote either, but the downvote is justifiable. You put the Maclaurin series of $\sin$ and proceed to write $\lim \sin x \cong x$ (whatever that means), and then you put $\lim \frac{\sin x}{x} \cong 1$ (whatever that means again). Those are unclear things that can confuse the OP.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo Those are standard notations. I don't realise why you fail to understand them. Or some thing else you are talking of?

Comment: @SchrodingersCat No, those are not standard notations. You are confusing with the usual notation for *functions*. There is no sense in $\lim \sin x \cong x$. One is a number, the other is a... variable? Unless you explicitly say what you mean by such symbols, this is not clear.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo which one is a number? And it is $\simeq$.. please correct whatever you are writing.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat You can divide by $0$ when taking limits.  Recall how to do rational functions.

Comment: @SimpleArt Thats fine. Earlier you didn't mention taking limit.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat No problem.

Comment: $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \sin x$ is a number, namely zero. Define what is $0 \simeq x$.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo $0\simeq0$ is what I believe to be the argument here.

Comment: Funny enough, if you had replaced "For $x \rightarrow 0$, we can say $\sin x \simeq x$" by "So, $\sin x \simeq x$" and stopped right there, the answer would be concise but correct, since $\sin x \simeq x$ *means* $\frac{\sin x}{x} \rightarrow 1$. What you wrote after that is simply confused and ill-defined.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo I believe you are mistaking $\simeq$ with ~

Comment: @AloizioMacedo From your last comment," So $\sin x \simeq x$" is totally wrong. It holds only when $x$ is near $0$ and then we can neglect the higher powers of $x$ in the maclaurin series. Get the point?

Comment: ... There is no reason arguing over a ill-defined concept. Since this comment section is becoming clustered, I'll not respond until the issue has been properly addressed: What is your precise definition of "a $\simeq$ b"?

Comment: @AloizioMacedo Means $a$ "is nearly/almost equal to" $b$.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat Sorry for the unnecessary irony in my last comment. That was not constructive to the discussion, and I apologize. I let myself get caught by the moment.

What happens is the following: your definition is not precise enough for the issue here, it is very naive. One might argue that $\sin x \cong \frac{2}{3}x$ for $x$ close to $0$ since they are "nearly/almost equal", and arrive at a different limit, following your reasoning. What happens is that you want to define *in what sense are they nearly/almost equal*. (...)

Comment: (...) If you try to make that notion precise for this context, you will arrive at the definition that it should mean $\frac{\sin x}{x} \rightarrow 1$ (which means, naively, that they have the "same assymptoptic behaviour"). So, your argument becomes circular.

What you can do is directly conclude that $\frac{\sin x}{x} \rightarrow 1$ from the taylor series, without passing by that naive framework. You use the uniform convergence of a power series and that justifies you dividing by $x$ in each summand and then passing the limit as $x\rightarrow 0$ in each summand, which arrives at $1$.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo Your final 2 comments had strong logic as to why my argument was circular. Thanks for helping, and I have tried to make proper corrections. See if it fits now.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat Yes, that is it. However, just to be extremely clear, uniform convergence is used when you pass that limit (which is a limit, coloquially speaking, "term by term"), not on division per se (division only uses the fact that it is not zero).

Again, I'm sorry for the possible annoyance that my comment may have caused you. I deleted it due to respect, but in order not to "vanish" my blame, I leave again my apologies here.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo It's okay. Again thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

The graph is absolutely correct, it just misses a big empty circle representing the point of discontinuity. A point is an infinitely small entity, so it cannot be seen. It is just an identity, a position. It has no dimensions. So that point, namely, $x=0,y=1$ is missing.

Answer (score -2):

Consider the Maclaurin expansion of $\frac{sin(x)}{x}$

$$sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-...$$

Dividing by $x$ you get a series that has a value of $1$ at $x=0$

Comment: At $x=0$, you cannot divide by $x$, since division by $0$ is meaningless.

Comment: Maybe you can't, but I just did.

Comment: that's hilarious.